# Are there any collections of Optical Flow code?

Tags: opticalflow

I'm currently searching for optical flow code of all sorts (mainly implementations of algorithms), for the purpose of gathering them into a list, which can later be published in the form of a website.

Has there been any such effort before? If so, did it get anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Matlab/C++: http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/OpticalFlow/
CS UMD EDU: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~ogale/download/code.html
I found quite a few more references by [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=optical+flow+code) it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I've gone over the first already, but I haven't seen the second link yet.

Answer (score 3):

Also see, [CVPapers](http://www.cvpapers.com/rr.html)

Matlab/C++/ OpenCL-GPU [Robust Local Optical Flow](http://www.nue.tu-berlin.de/menue/forschung/projekte/rlof/)

Matlab C++ [The FlowLib](http://gpu4vision.icg.tugraz.at/index.php?content=downloads.php)

C++/ Cuda GPU [KLT+SIFT](http://cs.unc.edu/~ssinha/Research/GPU_KLT/)

Comment: Or visit the optical flow benchmark webpage e.g. KITTI http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_stereo_flow.php?benchmark=flow